# Cypress Test Imports API Functions To Call, But Imports Within App Files Fail

Tags: typescript, import, cypress, e2e-testing, web-api-testing

I am attempting to run API function tests through Cypress.
In order to do that I need to import the file from the application with all the functions I want to run.

I have the following at the top of my `test.cy.ts` file:

```js
///<reference types="cypress" />

import { authStore } from '../../source/store/theAuthenticationStore'; //edited for security
```

Within `theAuthenticationStore.ts`, authStore is declared/defined as:

```js
export const authStore = defineStore('auth', { // etc...
```

But at the top of said file, the directories of imports start with `@/<relative to baseUrl here>` as a shortcut.
Example:

```js
import { getAuthService, IUserSesh, ResetToken } from '@/serviceStuff/authenticationService'; //edited for security
```

When I run my tests I get the following error (again edited for security):

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./source/store/theAuthenticationStore.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/client_api/buyer' in 'C:\Users\UserName\...\repo\source\store'
resolve '@/client_api/buyer' in 'C:\Users\UserName\...\repo\source\store'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Users\UserName\...\repo\package.json (relative path: ./source/store)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      C:\Users\UserName\...\repo\source\store\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      // ... breaks down entire directory looking for node_modules
      C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\Users\UserName\...\repo\node_modules
        using description file: C:\Users\UserName\...\repo\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: C:\Users\UserName\...\repo\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/@/client_api/buyer)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      looking for modules in C:\Users\UserName\...\node_modules
        No description file found
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\UserName\...\repo\node_modules\@\client_api\buyer doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Users\UserName\...\repo\node_modules\@\client_api\buyer.js doesn't exist
            
        as directory
          C:\Users\UserName\...\node_modules\@\client_api\buyer doesn't exist
[C:\Users\UserName\...\source\store\node_modules]
// ... Break it down, now.
[C:\node_modules]
[C:\Users\UserName\...\node_modules\package.json]
[C:\Users\UserName\...\repo\node_modules\@\client_api\buyer]
[C:\Users\UserName\...\repo\node_modules\@\client_api\buyer.js]
// ... Tries buyer as every file type, in and out of repo.
[C:\Users\UserName\...\node_modules\@\client_api\buyer.tsx]
 @ ./source/store/theAuthenticationStore.ts 45:16-47
 @ ./cypress/e2e/test.cy.ts
 
    at Watching.handle [as handler] (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\12.13.0\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\node_modules\@cypress\webpack-preprocessor\dist\index.js:212:23)
    at // ... Looks through entire Cypress Cache for it. It's not there. The end.
```

However, I have `node_modules` at `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.11.1\node_modules`, `client_api/buyer` exists in the repo and I am unable to change the presence of the `@` in my other files since it's used in ALL the other files.
Quite frankly, I am unsure what to do.

I have been using [this website](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/03/stop-using-page-objects-and-start-using-app-actions/#:%7E:text=and%205%20seconds.-,Application%20actions,-Imagine%20that%20instead) to help with the tests.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
If any further information is needed, I will edit them in upon request.

**EDIT:**

I have now tried putting

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
        "types": ["cypress", "node"],
        "baseUrl": "..",
        "paths": {
            "@/src/*": ["src/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["../node_modules/cypress", "*/*.ts", "**/*.ts", "../../src"]
}
```

in my `repo/cypress/tsconfig.json` file instead of just my `repo/tsconfig.json` file, with help from [this website](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/using-ts-aliases-in-cypress-tests/), but to no avail. I am getting the same error.

Any help is still appreciated.

**EDIT 2:**

I have been trying to find the ES5 equivalent to webpack's `cypress/plugins/cy-ts-preprocessor.js` file. Is it `.eslintrc.js`? If anyone knows if it is and how to handle aliases my problem will be solved.